# Agora Web SDK renewToken fails

Tags: agora.io

I am using agora to build a web app with audio/video call functionality. So far everything works fine. But when I try to renew the token of a connection I receive the following errors:

[image]

The code I use to generate the token is exact the same as for the token I use to join the channel (which works).

Generate the token (server side):

```js
const getToken = (user: User, channelName: string): string => {
  const currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  const uid = userToUid(user);

  return RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithAccount(
    process.env.AGORA_APP_ID,
    process.env.AGORA_APP_CERTIFICATE,
    channelName,
    uid,
    RtcRole.PUBLISHER,
    currentTimestamp + parseInt(process.env.AGORA_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_SECONDS, 10),
  );
};
```

Join the channel (client side):

```js
const uid = userToUid(user);

const token = await fetchChannelToken(user.id, channelName);

await client.join(appid, channelName, token, uid);
```

Renew the token (client side):

```js
client.on('token-privilege-will-expire', async () => {
  if (!client) return;

  const token = await fetchChannelToken(user.id, channelName);

  await client.renewToken(token);
});
```

The token lifetime is 10min and I also tried to renew it before the `'token-privilege-will-expire'` event occurs (e.g. 30 sec after joining the channel).

Has anyone a clue what could cause this? Could it be related to using string user accounts instead of the recommended integer user ID's?